# Definition of Predicate Calculus.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

This question is from [Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekrajicek/mendelson.pdf) by Elliot Mendelson.

in page 69-70 , a first order theory $K$ is defined to have 5 logical axioms and a (possibly empty) set of proper axioms.A first. order theory in which there are no proper axioms is called a  first-order predicate calculus.Now , if a theory $K$ has no proper axioms , then it will be a predicate calculus and it has 5 specific axioms.So there seems to be only 1 predicate calculus.

But then at exercise 2.63(c) of the book ,there is this exercise:

> Prove that no predicate calculus is a  scapegoat theory.

This seems to say that there can be multiple kinds of predicate calculus , but I cant really understand how.Am I missing something?

Comment: Page 70: A FO theory in which there are no proper axioms is called a FO *predicate calculus*. Thus, we have specific non-logical symbols, like e.g. $\in$ but no **proper** axioms about them.

Comment: But how does that imply that there can be more than 1 type of predicate calculus?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to start from the definition of *first-order language* [page 57]:

> **A** [*emphasis mine*] first-order langugage $\mathscr L$ is [...]

> > (f) a non-empty set of predicate letters.

Thus, we have e.g. **the** first-order language of *set theory*, with the binary predicate symbol $\in$ [in Mendelson's formalism $A_1^2$] and a constant symbol $\emptyset$, as well as **the** first-order language of *arithmetic*, with the function symbol $s$ (the *successor*), the binary predicate symbol $\lt$ and a constant symbol $0$.

**If** there are no proper axioms, the corresponding theory will be called **a** [*emphasis mine*] first-order *predicate calculus*.

Thus

> are there multiple predicate calculus?

Yes; there will be the predicate calculus for the first-order language of set theory, **with** non-logical symbols: $\in, \emptyset$, but **without** proper axioms involving them, as well as the predicate calculus for the first-order language of arithmetic, **with** non-logical symbols: $s, \lt, 0$, but **without** proper axioms involving them.

The non-logical symbols will occur in instances of logical axioms, like e.g.: $\forall x (x  \in \emptyset) \to (\emptyset \in \emptyset)$.

In this predicate calculus we will prove all valid formulas using the proper symbols of the language, like the formula above as well as $\emptyset = \emptyset$, in the corresponding version of predicate calculus with *equality* [page 94].

Of course, we cannot prove with them "proper" theorems of the corresponding theories, like e.g. $\lnot \exists x (x \in \emptyset)$, because they are not valid.