# Defining an FOL language

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I am looking for sources (beginner level) which teach one how to define a language based on first order logic, define syntax and semantics, prove properties, etc. I am also looking for beginner sources that teach proving theorems in the context of FOL and propositional logic. Thanks

Comment: This is something I've been looking for myself. I've found that first, you must define a formal system. There's some great examples of how this has been done before in the wiki article for [Propositional Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Generic_description_of_a_propositional_calculus)

Comment: See e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198997/how-is-first-order-logic-language-completely-determined-by-non-logical-symbol)